# Error uploading photo to Firebase from real device

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

When I try to upload photo from gallery to Firebase Storage on real device iPhone SE, I'v got an error in log Swift:

> Failed to issue sandbox extension for file
>   file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1237.JPG, errno = 1 Error
>   uploading: An unknown error occurred, please check the server
>   response.

But if I trying it from Swift simulator - all is ok.

Code for uploading photo:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *), let referenceURL = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.referenceURL] as? URL {
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [referenceURL], options: nil)
        let asset = assets.firstObject
        asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { [weak self] (contentEditingInput, info) in
            let imageFile = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL
            let flip = arc4random_uniform(9999)
            var rand = String(flip)
            let filePath = "myFiles/myFile"
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            let imgPath = strongSelf.storageRef.child(filePath)
                imgPath.putFile(from: imageFile!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        let nsError = error as NSError
                        print("Error uploading: \(nsError.localizedDescription)")
                        return
                    }
                    imgPath.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                        guard let downloadURL = url
                            else {
                            print("error")
                            return
                        }
                        print(downloadURL)
                        strongSelf.sendMessage(withData: [Constants.MessageFields.imageURL: downloadURL.absoluteString])
                    }

            }
        })
```

**Please help me fix it.**

Comment: Hey, what was your solution or work around for this issue?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you have not added permission for the app to access your gallery?.
In case you have added please ensure you click Allow when Access dialog box is shown.

Comment: Permissions for gallery was added a long.time ago.